# Image Insertion and size comparison in Excel

Tags: image, excel, vba, colors, image-size

I would like to achieve the following in excel,I am not sure whether VBA is sufficient. I have tried to code myself for a day, but could get my code executed. Could someone kindly help?

1. insert a image from hard drive in column B, with the file name
   indicated in column A.
2. search whether a second version of the file
   exist. eg. if I inserted "abc.png", search whether "1_abc.png"
   exist. Mark the column with color if the second version exist.
3. compare the size of the two file, if the size of "abc.png" and
   "1_abc.png" are not the same, write a commend in the column C.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: show the code you already have to help you improve it...

Comment: Sub InsertIcon()
'find icon and insert
Dim name As String ' file path of the pic

For a = 1 To 1000
name = Cells(a, 4).Value
'MsgBox (name)
    Cells(a, 8).Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(name).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 40
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 10
  Next
End Sub

Comment: I have complete the Insertion part, but not the comparison part.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub InsertIcon()'find icon and insert
Dim name As String ' file path of the pic
For a = 1 To 1000
name = Cells(a, 4).Value
'MsgBox (name)
Cells(a, 8).Select
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(name).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 40
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 10
Next
End Sub
```

This is the code I used to solve insertion problem.